# User control not getting painted c#

Tags: c#, winforms, double-buffering

I have an application in which I can move from 1 user control to many user controls. When I was moving to many controls, I was getting flickering issues.
To solve the flickering I enabled ***Double Buffering*** via -

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
        return cp;
    }
}
```

It indeed solved the issue of **flickering**. But introduced a new problem, In which sometimes my user control isn't painted completely. A black window is appeared. To solve this, I need to minimize and maximize the software and it appears properly.

> What I think is that, while double buffering is painting all the user
>   controls at one shot, One or more user control is still generating its
>   controls. And at the time of master painting, that control was not
>   ready.

Here is the image for getting proper idea -

### [image]

As shown in image, There is one form, containing 4 user controls in this particular scenario. Each user control further, contains other controls/user controls.

What is probably going wrong in this issue?

Comment: Have you tried calling `Invalidate()` in `ResizeEnd` event?

Comment: @Sandeep No man, it wasn't helpful.

Comment: Got similar issue but for little less complicated user controls. This issue was resolved by calling `Invalidate()` in `ResizeEvent` to handle main window movement. And by calling `Invalidate` in `MouseUp` event for user control movement.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing `TrasnsparencyKey` in form design from black to another color but not black, try one color that you are not using.